# IE Not Displaying Certain parts of my Site

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser

IE does not display the title and the sidebar on mysite. To see an example: http://laseretchline.com/products/bagTags.html.

Chrome and Firefox display properly, what do I need to change to get IE to work?

Comment: IE version 9 is the one I'm checking

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems to be in this line:

```
Cufon.replace('h1, h2, h3, h5, #sidebar li, .footer', { hover: 'true' });
```

Did you check if this library is compatible with IE9?

Check this article: [Cufon display issues in IE9 beta / here's a fix](http://www.vfxdude.com/forum/topic/cufon-display-issues-in-ie9-beta-heres-a-fix)